# Get user id by passing token in Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-passport

How can i get user id by passing token in Laravel?
I wanna to get the user token from request then send user avatar to him.

Comment: you said by passed token to laravel. Means something like jwt? What kind of token?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try This**

```
 $userid = Auth::guard('api')->user()->id;
 echo $userid;
```

Comment: Hope its Work!!.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in your controller

```
$user = Auth::user();

if ($user)
{
    return $user->avatar;
}
```

You can use `Auth` to get the authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Crypt](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/encryption#using-the-encrypter) Facade for encrypting and decrypting user id and pass it for your case.

I recommend checking [API token authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication), if you don't want to use it then in very simple and native way you can do something like this:

1. Create a token with user id encrypted in it.
2. Pass the token to input form, keep it as hidden form value.
3. On receiving the request with token, decrypt the token, extract id and fetch result and send.

Some Security recommendation:

- [Depends on use case] while encrypting and decrypting, along with
  user_id also append date time value like timestamp. So that you can perform token expiration verification.

```
// Controller
public function index() {
    return view('/top/index.php', [$token => $this->getToken()]);
}

private function getToken() {
    $id = '100001'; //get from db or wherever u need

    // this just example
    return Crypt::encrypt( $id. ':' . time();
}
```

then in the Form/blade

```
<form>
....
    <input hidden value = "{{ $token }}" name='token'>
....
    <input type submit>

</form>
```

On receiving post request

```
// controller
public function postIndex(Request $request) {
    $userId = $this->extractIdFromToken($request->input('token'));
    ...
    ...
}

private function extractIdFromToken($token) {
    if ($token === null) {
       throw new \Exception('Missing token');
    }

    $tokenValue = explode(':', Crypt::decrypt($token));
    // do verification of time needed else go to next
    return $tokenValue[0] ?? null;
}
```